# Как через SSH посмотреть вывод процесса, запущенного в терминале

Tags: linux, ssh

Python скрипт запущен в терминале. Можно ли подключившись через SHH увидеть вывод данного процесса?

```
tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1 
strace -p1234 -s9999 -e write
```

Вышеперечисленные способы не дали результата.

Comment: Вам нужен *ttysnoop*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте в сессии `screen`, `tmux` и им подобных. Потом сможете подключиться к ней и посмотреть, что там творится.